# MediaRecoder not recording HTML5 Audio

Tags: html, web-audio-api, mediarecorder-api

I have a .wav audio in a html page and want to record it using javascript. I want to record from the speakers. The audio plays, is being sent to the speakers, and the format is supported but the sound is not being recorded by mediaRecorder(). When the file is downloaded it is empty.

I'm not sure what to check next?

```
//start playing sound button, html page
document.querySelector(".start").addEventListener("click", function() {
audioZero.play();
});

//start recording sound button, html page
document.querySelector(".startrec").addEventListener("click", function() {
    mediaRecorder.start();
    console.log("recorder started");
 });

 //stop recording sound button, html page
 document.querySelector(".stoprec").addEventListener("click", function() {
    mediaRecorder.requestData();
    mediaRecorder.stop();
 });

let audioContext = new AudioContext();

//get sound 
let audioZero = document.getElementById("audio0")

// creates a link between audio context and file
const maracas = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioZero)

let gainNode = audioContext.createGain()
maracas.connect(gainNode)

// creates link to the speaker
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
console.log(audioContext.destination);

gainNode.gain.value = 1;

//Gets stream of data from the speaker output - gives the ability to store
const dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

//This records the stream 
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);

let chunks = [];

//when data is available an event is raised, this listens for it
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt, evt.data);
    chunks.push(evt.data);
};

mediaRecorder.onstop = function(evt) {
   // Make blob out of our blobs, and open it.
   var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : "audio/webm;codecs=opus" });

   var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
   anchorTag.setAttribute('download', 'download');
   anchorTag.innerHTML="download me";

   // creates the download link
   anchorTag.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

   document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);

   chunks = [];

};
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating the MediaStreamDestinationNode, you need to connect the sound-producing part of your audio graph to it - it doesn't automatically get all sound sent to the audioContext.destination just because it's another destination node.  (You can't record "everything that goes to the speakers" - that could be a cross-origin violation.)

Add this line right after creating your "dest" node:

```
gainNode.connect(dest);
```

You do need to call mediaRecorder.start() at some point, too - not sure if that just wasn't in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The mediaRecorder is in one of the button links. Could you explain how that's different to     gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
as I thought I connected the sound to the speakers with that.

Comment: It's pretty much correct to think of audioContext.destination as "the speakers" - but although MediaStreamDestinationNode is a type of destination node, it's not the same node as the speakers.  Destination nodes are just anything that's an ultimate destination - e.g., can't be connected to anything else.  You need to independently connect the audio feed to the media recorder.

Comment: In short, you can have OTHER destination nodes in your graph, aside from just "the speakers".